# Javascript /n is showing as part of the string

Tags: javascript, newline

Notice the 2nd to last line with the concatenated '\n'. It seems to be added to part of the string instead of acting as line breaks, as I want them to.

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

I'm trying to show this in an online coding exercise environment. There is no HTML involved.

```
var currentInventory = [
  {
    name: 'Brunello Cucinelli',
    shoes: [
      {name: 'tasselled black low-top lace-up', price: 1000},
      {name: 'tasselled green low-top lace-up', price: 1100},
      {name: 'plain beige suede moccasin', price: 950},
      {name: 'plain olive suede moccasin', price: 1050}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Gucci',
    shoes: [
      {name: 'red leather laced sneakers', price: 800},
      {name: 'black leather laced sneakers', price: 900}
    ]
  }
];

function renderInventory(inventoryList) {
  var summaryList = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < inventoryList.length; i++) {
    var currentElement = inventoryList[i];
    var designerName = currentElement.name;
    var shoes = currentElement.shoes;

    for (var j = 0; j < shoes.length; j++) {
      var shoe = shoes[j].name;
      var price = shoes[j].price;

      summaryList.push(designerName + ', ' + shoe + ', ' + price);
    }
  }
  var summaryString = turnListToString(summaryList);

  return summaryString;
}

function turnListToString(list) {
  var outputString = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    outputString += list[i] + '\n';
  }
```

Comment: If you are showing this in an element, use `<br>` instead of `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

`\n` will help you in adding a line break in an input box's value, but not in the `innerHTML` or `textContent`.

Use `</br>` instead

```
outputString += list[i] + '</br>';
```